# Punctuation, comma or not

Tags: commas, periods

You are beautiful, child, beautiful.

You are beautiful, child. Beautiful.

How should I punctuate the above sentence?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable, with the second one having a longer pause before the final *beautiful*.

It is true that, in general, punctuation and [prosody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosody_(linguistics)) are imperfectly correlated. But in a case like this, which seems to be reported speech (or possibly emulation of speech), the period will be interpreted as a longer prosodic break than a comma. So one answer is, use the one that better corresponds to how you would *say* it.

As far as which one you should *say*, that depends on what effect you want to have and on the broader context. The second one puts more emphasis on *beautiful*, and makes it sound more earnest. The first one sounds as if it is a comment about more than just the beauty—like the rest of the message is still to come.